# Animated text gets hidden after completion of the animation

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I had tried a simple animation. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dtcec301/).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="special_sec">
  <span class="sub_heading">About Us</span>
  <span class="sub_heading1">Services</span>
  <span class="sub_heading2">Portfolio</span>
  <span class="sub_heading3">Clients</span>
  <span class="sub_heading4">Contact Us</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.special_sec span { 
  font-size:30px; 
  list-style:none; 
  text-align:center; 
  padding:10px 0; 
  display:block; 
  animation:subheadinganimation 17s; 
  color: transparent;
}
```

In my CSS (`.special_sec span`), I have added `color: transparent`.

**My problem is:**

1. If `color` is transparent, after the animation all the text are getting hidden. See my fiddle.
2. If I remove this `color` property, all the text are initially visible. Then the animation also runs. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dtcec301/1/).

I want the text to be visible only after the delay timings that I have given. I can't understand the problem. What is the issue? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) as `forwards` so that the element would hold the state as at the final keyframe of the animation (which is `color: #000`). Without this setting, the element reverts back to its original state (`color: transparent`) after the animation is complete.

```css
animation: subheadinganimation 17s forwards;
```

```css
@keyframes subheadinganimation {
  0%, 30% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-2000px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-2000px);
    transform: translateX(-2000px);
  }
  33%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
    color: #000;
  }
}
.special_sec span {
  font-size: 30px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: block;
  animation: subheadinganimation 17s forwards;
  color: transparent;
}
span.sub_heading {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
span.sub_heading1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
span.sub_heading2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
span.sub_heading3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 9s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 9s;
  animation-delay: 9s;
}
span.sub_heading4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="special_sec">
  <span class="sub_heading">About Us</span>
  <span class="sub_heading1">Services</span>
  <span class="sub_heading2">Portfolio</span>
  <span class="sub_heading3">Clients</span>
  <span class="sub_heading4">Contact Us</span>
</div>
```